# Poisson process problem

Tags: probability

Problem statement below...

Customers of a store frequent it at a rate of 0.75 customers per minute following a Poisson process.

Exactly one customer goes into the store during a 2 minute span. What's the probability of the customer having come into the store before 1/2 a minute of the 2 minute span was up?

...I've tried a bunch of things but they're not working(I don't understand Poisson processes well). I think the random variable X ~ Exp(0.75) should give me probability involving times between events. I though it should be P(X < 1/2) * P(X > 1.5), the probability of an event occurring within 1/2 a minute and the probability of nothing happening for 1.5 minute since the intervals are independent or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B$ be the event exactly $1$ customer enters in the $2$ minute span. Let $A$ be the event that the customer enters in the first half-minute. We need to find the probability of $A\cap B$, which is $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

We have $\Pr(B)=e^{-1.5}\frac{(1.5)^1}{1!}$, since the number of cusomers in $2$ minutes has Poisson distribution parameter $(2)(0.75)$.

The event $A\cap B$ happens if there is $1$ customer in the first half minute and none in the next $1.5$. The probability of this is
$$e^{-0.375}\frac{(0.375)^1}{1!}\cdot e^{-1.125}.\tag{1}$$
Now divide the expression (1) by $\Pr(B)$. There will be a pleasant amount of cancellation.

The result can be obtained much more quickly if we have additional theory.

Comment: thanks, this cleared a lot up. What do you mean that the answer could be obtained much more quickly with additional theory?

Comment: You may know already about the conditional distribution of the number of hits in the interval $[0, a]$ given that there were $k$ hits in the interval $[0,a+t]$. It turns out this conditional distribution is binomial. But if this bit of theory about Poisson processes has not yet been covered (and I would guess it has not), don't worry about it.